# Accessing properties between calls using NSIS CLR.dll

Tags: .net, nsis

I am writing an installer using NSIS which needs to parse a block of JSON.

To achieve this I was hoping to be able to call a .Net dll which would parse the JSON and then in my NSIS script I could call properties on the class to retrieve back the data I need.

However, it appears that the NSIS CLR.dll has a problem where the state of a class is not maintained between calls.

My test .Net class is as follows:

```
namespace NSISTestDll
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        private bool _configured;

        public void Configure()
        {
            _configured = true;
        }


        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                if (_configured)
                {
                    return "John Doe";
                }
                return "Unconfigured";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And the part of my NSIS script that calls this is:

```
File "NSISTestDll.dll"
CLR::Call /NOUNLOAD "NSISTestDll.dll" "NSISTestDll.TestClass" "Configure" 0

CLR::Call /NOUNLOAD "NSISTestDll.dll" "NSISTestDll.TestClass" get_Name 0
pop $0  
MessageBox MB_OK $0
```

The MessageBox shows "Unconfigured" rather than the expected "John Doe".

Reading the forum on the CLR.dll the creater of the plugin does mention that this is a problem.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

One thing I was thinking of doing was writing a wrapper in C++ and using System.dll instead so that I can pass my needed values back directly to the NSIS script variables.

The other alternative is to parse the JSON for every property I need to retrieve, the JSON is small enough that this wouldn't impact performance too badly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a call like `CLR::Call /NOUNLOAD ...` /NOUNLOAD only applies to the CLR dll (The plugin) The CLR plugin itself would have to invent/support it's own parameter if it needed to keep NSISTestDll loaded

Comment: so is there a way to do what I want: Call a method which changes the state of a .Net class, and then access that changed state through properties?

Comment: You might have to modify the CLR plugin. Have you tried asking the plugin author?

Comment: the requirements shifted yesterday so that .Net can't be used so i'm going to be writing the parser in c++ anyway, probably equivalent to modifying the CLR plugin. Thanks for your help!